# pip install scrapy erro 1

Tags: python-3.x, pip, scrapy

Estou tentando instalar o Scrapy no vscode porém toda vez da um erro que não estou conseguindo resolver, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Andre\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sm77cvme\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Use
rs\\Andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sm77cvme\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --rec
ord 'C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d_x22glp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Andre\anaconda3\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, André, Tudo bem?
Este erro ocorre devido à falta de um pacote chamado Build Tools, ou Ferramentas de Compilação e é muito simples de resolver, você pode obtê-lo através do link [Baixar](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/visual-cpp-build-tools/)!